# How to use plist programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new in this field. So, can anyone explain how to use plist programmatically? From, where can I start , so that I can learn it properly?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/QuickStartPlist/QuickStartPlist.html

Answer (score -1):

You can access plist as same as NSDictionary. Plist provide data in key value formate.

-you can add your own plist file and use your plist as this way.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"plistname" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];

NSString *temp = [dict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-Your key name",key]];
```

Comment: Or more concisely: `NSString *value = dict[key];`.  There are two errors in your final line of code (3 if you include the fact the outer `stringWithFormat` is unnecessary).